# Implicit parameter "chaining" for DSL

Tags: scala, dsl

I have an idea (vague), to pass (or chain) some implicit value in this manner, not introducing parameters to block `f`:

```
def block(x: Int)(f: => Unit)(implicit v: Int) = {
  implicit val nv = v + x
  f
}

def fun(implicit v: Int) = println(v)
```

such that if I used something alike:

```
implicit val ii: Int = 0
block(1) {
  block(2) {
    fun
  }
}
```

It would print `3`.

If I could say `def block(x: Int)(f: implicit Int => Unit)`.

In other words I'm seeking for some design pattern which will allow me to implement this DSL: access some cumulative value inside nested blocks but without explicitly passing it as parameter. Is it possible? (`implicit`s are not necessary, just a hint to emphasize that I don't want to pass that accumulator explicitly). Of course upper code will print 0.

EDIT: One of possible usages: composing http routes, in a following manner

```
prefix("path") {
  prefix("subpath") {
    post("action1") { (req, res) => do action }
    get("action2") { (req, res) => do action }
  }
}
```

Here `post` and `get` will access (how?) accumulated prefix, say `List("path", "subpath")` or `"/path/subpath/"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [`DynamicVariable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.util.DynamicVariable) for this. It's really simple to use, and thread-safe:

```
val acc: DynamicVariable[Int] = new DynamicVariable(0)

def block(x: Int)(f: => Unit) = {
  acc.withValue(acc.value + x)(f)
}

def fun = println(acc.value)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thanks! Never heard about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Passing state via `implicit` is dirty and will lead to unexpected and hard to track down bugs. What you're asking to do is build a function that can compose in such a way that nested calls accumulate over some operation and anything else uses that value to execute the function?

```
case class StateAccum[S](init: S){
  val op: S => S
  def flatMap[A <: S](f: S => StateAccum[A]) ={
    val StateAccum(out) = f(s)
    StateAccum(op(init, out))
  }
  def apply(f: S => A) = f(init)
}
```

which could allow you do exactly what you're after with a slight change in how you're calling it.

Now, if you really want the nested control structures, your apply would have to use an implicit value to distinguish the types of the return such that it applied the function to one and a `flatMap` to `StateAccum` returns. It gets crazy but looks like the following:

```
 def apply[A](f: S => A)(implicit mapper: Mapper[S, A]): mapper.Out = mapper(this, f)

 trait Mapper[S, A]{
   type Out
   def apply(s: StateAccum[S], f: S => A): Out
 }

 object Mapper extends LowPriorityMapper{
   implicit def acuum[S, A <: S] = new Mapper[S, StateAccum[A]]{
     type Out = StateAccum[A]
     def apply(s: StateAccum[S], f: S => StateAccum[A]) = s.flatMap(f)
   }
 }

 trait LowPriorityMapper{
   implicit def acuum[S, A] = new Mapper[S, A]{
     type Out = A
     def apply(s: StateAccum[S], f: S => A) = f(s.init)
   }
 }
```

Comment: Well, this may be of some practical usage in other cases, but in my case I want a DSL which will allow nesting `f`'s and using some value there, like `block(1) { something using the cumulative value; block(2) { something using the cumulative value; } }`. `for` is unsuitable for this.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use `Mapper`? still cannot get into it

Comment: @dmitry That's ok, my for-comp version wouldn't do what you wanted. The edit to it will, however. It does involve "magic."

Comment: @dmitry I'm taking it into type-level "magic." It works via implicit priority. You change the "apply" to have an implicit value and based upon the return type of the function, it'll "just work" the way you want.

Comment: Well, even in this case I don't want that every block `f` would need to handle accumulator. I just want it to be accessible somehow. Like if it was implicit or some property which `f` can access, but only if it needs to. Not as an explicit parameter.

Comment: @dmitry Then I either don't understand what you want and could use a better explanation or what you are asking to do is impossible.

Comment: Added some use case to question. Maybe it will be clearer.